# Secure different endpoints with different OAuth2 services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is there any way to configure spring security to use a certain authorization for a group of endpoints and another authorization for another group?

For example I want to authorize all endpoints that start with **/facebook** to  use the Facebook login consent screen and endpoints that start with **/google** to use Google login consent screen.

I configured the properties for Spring Boot 2.x OAuth Client but I don't know how to configure the **HttpSecurity** object.
I think I can achieve this by implementing multiple **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter**, one for Facebook and one for Google, but I am not sure how.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks!